# Meteor React subscription delay

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have this little snippet of code:

```
getSearchQuery(evt) {
    let query = evt.target.value;

    Meteor.subscribe('searchResults', query, function() {
      console.log('subscription ready');
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
          <TextField
            hintText='Hint text'
            onChange={this.getSearchQuery.bind(this)}
            fullWidth={true}
          />
    )
  }
```

After typing first letter in input I expect in console 'subscription ready' output, but this output appears only after typing the second letter. In other words the 'subscription ready' output delays till the next letter typing.

For example if the search string is '123', typing '123' will result in two 'subscription ready' outputs, while I am expecting for three.

Is it possible to fix this problem somehow?

Comment: Show your publish function try changing "onChange" to "onKeyUp" inside <TextField />

Comment: The problem was with publication, ```Meteor.publish('searchResults', function(query) {
  check(query, String);
  if (query.length >= 2) {
    let items = Items.find(
      { $text: {
          $search: query
        }
      },
      {
        fields: {
          searchScore: {
            $meta: 'textScore'
          }
        },
        sort: {
          searchScore: {
            $meta: 'textScore'
          }
        }
      }
    );
    return items;
  }
});```

Comment: > 2 ;) is what fixed?

Comment: I currently removed >=2 condition, I will check on client

Comment: @IlanHasanov please add as answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are passing onChange prop to  I recommend that you use `onKeyPress` see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events as It's pure react event, as for the subscription ready log. Make sure you made proper conditions in your publish function, instead of `.length >= 2` to .`length > 2`.